# Django validate m2m model field

Tags: python, django

I've a simple m2m relation of User and Client model in my Django 1.7 application.
The m2m field is declared inside the Client model.

I wish to validate the User value of m2m relation when I save or update a Client instance.
My validation consists to check if the User has some properties, if true save Client and the 2m2 relation, if false, raise a ValidationError.

Where I should put this logic?? I need to create an intermediate m2m model??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: how to validate m2m relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362251/django-how-to-validate-m2m-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add this validation in the `pre_add` stage of the [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal handler.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you cannot raise `ValidationError` in signal handler code as it won't be handled correctly (in the admin, for example) and you may end up with a 500 error that is a headache to trace.

Answer (score 0):

As this validation should be enforced at both save and update, its best to [override the `clean_fields` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields) of the *model*.

Comment: How can I check in my Client clean_fields(self, exclude) overrided method if the User have some valid properties??
User is already saved in the db....

In the clean_fields() I have a self (Client) instance... that it have self.clients ManyToManyRelatedManager (from m2m relation).

Comment: You'll have a reference to it through the m2m field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I've override the Client model (where I have declare a m2m users field) clean_fields() ...
Inside that method I have, at runtime:  self.users that is a ManyToManyRelatedManager not a specific user instance that has been selected. 
What is wrong?

Comment: Ok the self.users.all() return me the list of users of the client, but it is the list of the previous users... not the users that I have selected in the Client admin form and I need to validate.

Comment: If you only need validation on the admin form, then add the validation code there.

Comment: No, I need validation on the model. I will use it with django_restframework later.
At the time, I'm using an intermediate model and I've override there the clean(self) method... I'm not sure if this is a good practice.

Comment: m2m fields are updated after cleaning. Therefore this does not work.